# Load a BLOB video at a specific time

Tags: javascript, video, blob

I would to load a BLOB video as Youtube or Netflix for example.
That is, load the video from 0s to 10s in BLOB, display it and then load the video from 10s to 20s.

I thought about doing this code (which works without the #t =0,10 but waiting for the entire video to load before returning it).

```
var query = new XMLHttpRequest();
var videolink = "test.mp4";
var videobalise = $("video");
var get = videolink + "#t=0,10";

query.open("GET", get, true);
query.responseType = "blob";
query.onload = function(){

   if(this.status === 200){

        var currentTime = videobalise[0].currentTime;
        var paused = false;
        if(!videobalise[0].paused) paused = true;

        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        var videoBlob = this.response;
        var video = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);

        videobalise.attr("src", video);
        videobalise[0].currentTime = currentTime;

        if(paused == true){
            videobalise[0].play();
        }

   }
}
query.send();
```

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for Netflix, but for YouTube, that's not what they do.

The blob URI you see as the `src` of their `<video>` element points to a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) object, not to a Blob.

---

Now, the `#t` fragment identifier in a MediaElement `src` works only for MediaElements.
MediaElements will try to load only the required data from the server. This is done thanks to [Range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests). But it requires that the media's metadata has been already fetched and parsed, so that the browsers can know at which byte-range the next data to load is located.
The `#t` fragment identifier is just a way to tell the browser that we are only interested in the range being defined in there, and thus, this fragment identifier also needs that the media's metadata are accessible, and provide the correct bytes offset.

All this to tell that you actually need the full file to be available at the URI on which you set this `#t` fragment identifier.

So in your case, you would have to load the full file from the original URI, and only on the blob URI that you'll set as the `<video>`'s `src` would you append the fragment identifier:

```js
var url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm";
fetch(url) // fetch the whole file
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const blobURI = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const fragId = '#t=5' // starts at 5s
    vid.src = blobURI + fragId; // here you set the fragId
  });
```

```css
video{height:100vh}
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls></video>
```

So this is probably not what you want, since you would actually load the full file.

But I guess that what you really wanted was a way to hide the original file, in a desperate attempt to block your users from downloading it. Then, I am sorry to tell you that this won't work at all, because your AJAX request is clearly visible.
Note that even fetching yourself by range and using a MediaSource like YT won't work either, YT videos are actually downloadable.

The best move if you **really** want to do that might be to use the [Encrypted Media Extensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encrypted_Media_Extensions_API).